# Не создаётся соединение с сервером MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Вот такая ошибка при проверке соединения:

Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете нашёл два способа решения:

1. Включить службу "MySQL". Проблема в том, что в списке служб у меня нет такой службы.
2. Через установщик MySQL зайти в "Type and Networking". Но у меня установщик вообще другой, не такой как в гайдах. В моём установщике нет этого пунка.

Помогите устранить ошибку и подключиться к серверу.

Comment: Операционная система какая

Comment: У вас не установлен и не запущен сам MySql-сервер - вот и не может клиент подсоединиться к тому. чего нет. Установите MySql-сервер для начала, запустите, а потом к нему подключайтесь.

Comment: @void Спасибо... Очень помогли.